# Add javascript scolbar & effects to Block from module

Tags: blocks, javascript, feeds, theming

I have a block that was created with Social Feed Module. The block aggregate social feeds. I want to add a scroll-bar to the block it self. I have seen some examples:http://mydrupal.com/add_scrollbars_in_blocks

However, I would like the block scroll-bar to be visible ONLY when the user hovers over the scroll-bar. I would think I would need to use javascript with the scrolbar? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably bad usability because you would want your users to know that a block has scrolling content, but you could do something like this.

```
$(".block .content").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("overflow","scroll");
  },function(){
  $(this).css("overflow","hidden");
});
```